# Uploading file to PouchDB/CouchDB

Tags: javascript, cordova, file-upload, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm building a mobile app with Cordova. I am using PouchDB for local storage so the app works without internet. PouchDB syncs with a CouchDB server so you can access your data everywere.

Now, i've got to the point where I need to add a function to upload (multiple) files to a document. (files like .png .jpg .mp3 .mp4 all the possible file types).

My original code without the file upload:

```
 locallp = new PouchDB('hbdblplocal-'+loggedHex);
function addItem() {
    //get info
    var itemTitle = document.getElementById('itemTitle').value;
    var itemDesc = document.getElementById('itemDesc').value;
    var itemDate = document.getElementById('itemDate').value;
    var itemTime = document.getElementById('itemTime').value;

    //get correct database
    console.log(loggedHex);
    console.log(loggedInUsername);

    //add item to database
    var additem = {
    _id: new Date().toISOString(),
        title: itemTitle,
        description: itemDesc,
        date: itemDate,
        time: itemTime
    };
    locallp.put(additem).then(function (result){
        console.log("Added to the database");
        location.href = "listfunction.html";
    }).catch(function (err){
        console.log("someting bad happened!");
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

I'll add a link to a JSfiddle where I show my attempt to add the file upload. i've also included the html part.

link to jsfiddle: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/thomagron/w71d6o24/)

I've noticed an error in the console about there not being a content-type.

Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: Adding the **exact** error message will make it easier to help you ;)

Comment: Error: "Attachment file on document (id) is missing content_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not setting the `content_type` of your attachment right. Try changing `type` to `content_type` like so:

```
var additem = {
    _id: new Date().toISOString(),
    title: itemTitle,
    description: itemDesc,
    date: itemDate,
    time: itemTime,
    _attachments: {
      "file": {
        content_type: getFile.type,
        data: getFile
      }
    }
  };
```

Also see the [docs for working with attachments](https://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html#how-attachments-are-stored).

Comment: ah I see! I'm sure I had that before. anyway, Thank you